# web api design: date range query (only month and year)

Tags: .net, date, api-design

How to design api query for date range without day value?

For example,

Get inspections from October to December of 2015

```
list/inspections?from=2015-10&to=2015-12
```

wrong query example

```
list/inspections?from=2015-10-15&to=2015-12-10
```

Answer (score 1):

From by point of view, it's not wrong to pass the complete date (yyyy-MM-dd) from the client via the query-string. But on the server-side you can simply ignore the day value and make the query considering only year and month.
If you want to force the client to pass only year and month, the parameter must be considered as a string, and not a full date.